# How to hide header title but leave the back button in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was trying to look for ways on how to hide the header title or screen title on a particular screen only but retain the back button icon.

[image]

I tried using `headerShown` to false but it also remove the back button icon

```
<Stack.Screen
      name="Video Details"
      component={Video Details}
            headerLeft: ({onPress, focused}) => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
                <Image
                  source={icons.back}
                  resizeMode="contain"
                  style={{
                    width: 15,
                    height: 15,
                    marginLeft: 20,
                    tintColor: focused ? 'gray' : 'black',
                  }}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ),
          }}
        />
  />
```

Is there any property or workaround to just retain the back button icon and make the title of the screen hidden?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
 screenOptions={{headerBackTitleVisible:false}}
```

Comment: `<Stack.Screen
              name="BookDetailScreen"
              component={BookDetailScreen}
              options={{headerBackTitleVisible: false}}`

Comment: I tried it on one of the single screen but did not work.

Comment: you can try on navigator options

Comment: but I want to only affect one screen not all of them.

Comment: try this  options={{headerBackTitleVisible:false}}

Answer (score 1):

You can go for a better way. You can hide the default header using headerShown prop and by passing value false. It will hide the default header

```
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false
  }}
>
  <Stack.Screen name="YOUR_ROUTE_NAME" component={YOURCOMPONENT} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

After that you can design a custom Header component and set your desired props to render the data. And style it to remain on the top of the screen by setting its position to absolute or you can use flexbox to design it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can make headershown false and make the custom component for header
customise header according you want

Comment: Can site an example?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="Video Details"
  component={Video Details}
  options={{headerBackTitleVisible: false,
           headerLeft: ({onPress, focused}) => (
           <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
            <Image
              source={icons.back}
              resizeMode="contain"
              style={{
                width: 15,
                height: 15,
                marginLeft: 20,
                tintColor: focused ? 'gray' : 'black',
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response, but add

`options={{ title: null,  }}`

in your Screen Stack, hope this helps.

````
<Stack.Screen
      name="Video Details"
      component={Video Details}
      options={{ title: null,  }}
            headerLeft: ({onPress, focused}) => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
                <Image
                  source={icons.back}
                  resizeMode="contain"
                  style={{
                    width: 15,
                    height: 15,
                    marginLeft: 20,
                    tintColor: focused ? 'gray' : 'black',
                  }}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ),
          }}
        />
  />```
````